# MongoDB C# - how to do the following

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

How do I do the following using MongoDB with the C# driver for .NET.

Say I have the following collection (ignore if there are syntax errors):

```
{_id: "2312321321sdd", "Ticker": "AAPL", "CompanyName" : "APPLE", "Viewed": "2013-05-13"}
{_id: "2312321321sde", "Ticker": "AAPL", "CompanyName" : "APPLE", "Viewed": "2013-05-12"}
{_id: "2312321321sdf", "Ticker": "GOOG", "CompanyName" : "GOOGLE", "Viewed": "2013-05-12"}
{_id: "2312321321sdg", "Ticker": "MSFT", "CompanyName" : "MICROSOFT", "Viewed": "2013-05-12"}
{_id: "2312321321sdh", "Ticker": "MSFT", "CompanyName" : "MICROSOFT", "Viewed": "2013-05-11"}
```

Using C# and/or LINQ with the MongoDB driver, how do I get the latest 3 viewed items but also DISTINCT as well, so there are no double ups of the same TICKER. SO ideally the following would get returned:

```
{_id: "2312321321sdd", "Ticker": "AAPL", "CompanyName" : "APPLE", "Viewed": "2013-05-13"}
{_id: "2312321321sdf", "Ticker": "GOOG", "CompanyName" : "GOOGLE", "Viewed": "2013-05-12"}
{_id: "2312321321sdg", "Ticker": "MSFT", "CompanyName" : "MICROSOFT", "Viewed": "2013-05-12"}
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: perhaps a map reduce query where you map on Ticker and your reduce step is returning the entity with the latest Viewed.

Comment: perhaps like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785550/mongo-mapreduce-select-latest-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say this either uses LINQ or even much C#, but it's what you're after in MongoDB C# as it is today. Unfortunately, `Collection.AsQueryable()` won't get you far.

Aggregation Framework or MapReduce are the way to go. The set of distinct tickers needs to be modest, but here's AF:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoCollection<Tick> coll =
                new MongoClient("mongodb://11.11.11.11/test").GetServer()
                                                                .GetDatabase("test")
                                                                .GetCollection<Tick>("tix");

            var group = new BsonDocument
                {
                    {
                        "$group",
                        new BsonDocument
                            {
                                {
                                    "_id",  "$CompanyName"
                                },
                                {
                                    "LastViewed", new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                            {
                                                "$max", "$Viewed"
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                };

            foreach (
                var t in
                    coll.Aggregate(group,
                                   new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument("LastViewed", -1)),
                                   new BsonDocument("$limit", 3))
                        .ResultDocuments)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} last viewed {1}", t["_id"], t["LastViewed"]);
            }
    }

    public class Tick
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Ticker { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Viewed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MrJones, can't say, but it is server side and you won't have problems with 50k tickers; I'd put a descending index on Viewed (which unlike what I'm doing above should be an actual `$date`); I would also index the company name since you can probably afford to; unfortunately, I don't know of a way to make sure AF's operations are index-only, but shoot for that and check profiling dbs just in case they _will_ tell